# worldedit set block if block below is a certain block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-worldedit

I have this farm with multiple layers that needs to change to make it compatible with 1.14.4 everywhere there is a blue ice block I want to place a layer of snow on top of it. 
I found the overlay command however this doesnt work as there are multiple layers in this farm. Is there an easy way to put a snow layer on top of every Blue ice block?

Comment: Related, here is an extremely laggy solution in Vanilla: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/358484/171580 But hopefully there's a less laggy one in WorldEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using offset masks is the correct way to do this with WorldEdit.

If you want to replace every block above blue ice with snow, use `//replace >blue_ice snow`

Source: https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/usage/general/masks/#offset-mask